# Dynamic report using jrxml

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using iReport version 5.6.

Right now we're analyzing the requirement for a new project where the requirement is as follows.

We have a report which is designed in **jrxml** with almost 20 fields where user has to scroll to the right to get all values and hence tedious for the user when result size is too large.

Suggested requirement is as to configure the **jrxml** in such a way that user can select the column name for which the report should be generated.

Related image

[image]

We have done study on this and found the only possible solution may be to create a **jrxml** for each possible combination which seems to be not efficient for our project.

Could you please suggest is there any possible way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a seperate .jrxml file for each "view" you could duplicate the bands and use printWhen expressions to determine which band to display. Not a lot better than having separate .jrxml files but at least all the logic will be in the same file.

Another idea is to use parameters like showColA,showColB etc. Use those parameters to determine the column headers and values of those columns (this could get a little messy though)